# Media: Get only music audio files, not system audio files like game audio files, ringtones etc

Tags: android, audio, media-player, android-mediaplayer, audio-player, android-music-player

While trying to get music files (songs) as follows:

```
ContentResolver musicResolver = ctx.getContentResolver();
Uri musicUri = android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
Cursor musicCursor = musicResolver.query(musicUri, null, null, null,
                null);
```

Apart from music files, this also returns system audio files, like those of games etc. 
I only need the music audio files (songs) - how do i filter out others?